# JUnit Testing on adding and saving object to file, loading object from file

Tags: java, junit

So I have this assignment from my class where we need to test these test cases using JUnit.
I'm kind of lost on how to do the testing since the professor just skim through the JUnit chapter.
The problem that I have is Test case of saving appointment files, and loading of appointment files.
Can anyone help with the testing?
(instruction in image below)

[image: Programming task description]

Method from Appointment.java:

```java
public void occursOn(int year, int month, int day){
    System.out.println("Parent method.");
}
```

Appointment.java subclass (OneTime.java):

```java
public void occursOn(int year, int month, int day){
    LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.of(year,month,day);
    if (inputDate.isEqual(getDate())){
        System.out.println("One-Time Appointment on (Note : " + getDescription() + ")");
    }
    // check if date is after OneTime appointment in the same month
    if (inputDate.isAfter(getDate()) && inputDate.getMonthValue() == getDate().getMonthValue()){
        System.out.println("DATE IS AFTER appointment (Note: " +getDescription() +")");
    }
}
```

Appointment.java subclass (Daily.java):

```java
public void occursOn(int year, int month, int day){
    LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.of(year,month,day);

    if (inputDate.isAfter(getDate())){
        System.out.println("AFTER DAILY appointment (Note : " + getDescription() + ")");
    }
    if(inputDate.isEqual(getDate())){
        System.out.println("ON DAILY appointment (Note : " + getDescription() + ")");
    }
}
```

MainTest.java (JUnit testing class):

```java
import AppointmentPackage.Appointment;
import AppointmentPackage.Appointment;
import AppointmentPackage.Daily;
import AppointmentPackage.Monthly;
import AppointmentPackage.OneTime;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class MainTest {

@Test
void testOccursOn(){
    ArrayList<Appointment> aptList = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    Appointment appt1 = new OneTime(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test OneTime");
    Appointment appt2 = new Daily(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test Daily");
    Appointment appt3 = new Monthly(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test Monthly");
    aptList.add(appt1);
    aptList.add(appt2);
    aptList.add(appt3);

    System.out.println("Check date: 2020-10-15");
    for (Appointment a : aptList){
        a.occursOn(2020,10,15);
    }

    System.out.println("\nCheck date: 2020-11-15");
    for (Appointment a : aptList){
        a.occursOn(2020,11,15);
    }

    System.out.println("\nCheck date: 2020-12-05");
    for (Appointment a : aptList){
        a.occursOn(2020,12,05);
    }

    System.out.println("\nCheck date: 2020-09-15");
    for (Appointment a : aptList){
        a.occursOn(2020,9,15);
    }

}

@Test
void testSaving()  {
    ArrayList<Appointment> saveList = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    Appointment appt1 = new OneTime(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test OneTime");
    Appointment appt2 = new Daily(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test Daily");
    Appointment appt3 = new Monthly(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test Monthly");
    saveList.add(appt1);
    saveList.add(appt2);
    saveList.add(appt3);

    // Saving to file
    String fileName = "testSaveAppt.txt";
    FileWriter fwriter= new FileWriter(fileName, true);
    PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter(fwriter);

    for (Appointment a : saveList) {
        outputFile.println(a.getType() + " " + a.getDate() +  " " + a.getDescription());
    }

    outputFile.close();
}

@Test
void testLoad() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Loading from file
    String fileName = "testSaveAppt.txt";
    File myFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    ArrayList<Appointment> saveList = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    Appointment appt1 = new OneTime(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test OneTime");
    Appointment appt2 = new Daily(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test Daily");
    Appointment appt3 = new Monthly(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-15"), "Test Monthly");
    saveList.add(appt1);
    saveList.add(appt2);
    saveList.add(appt3);

    for (int i =0; i < saveList.size(); i++){
        String strFromFile = saveList.get(i).getType() + " " + saveList.get(i).getDate() + " " + saveList.get(i).getDescription();
        assertEquals(strFromFile, inputFile.nextLine());
    }

    inputFile.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make some research online about JUnit, this is not a complicated chapter. 
But here's a quick summarization : 
JUnit allows you to test your methods (you already knew that), the key part is using **Assert** methods to check if the results of these methods are what you were waiting for.

For exemple :

```
assertTrue(method()); // If the method returns true, then the test has passed !, otherwise there is an error
```

There are a lot a different asserts that you can use, but again, have a look online !